# Indian citizens holding J 1 visa travelling on cruise to Bahamas

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, bahamas, j1-visas

Indian citizens holding J1 visa in US want to travel to Bahamas on cruise. Do they need Bahamas visa ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Consulate General of the Commonwealth of The Bahamas](http://www.bahamasny.net/ApplicationFiles/Cruise_Ships.pdf), if you are going to (and will depart from) the island via a Cruise Ship, no visa is required for or from the Bahamas.

That pdf includes an phone number to call for information. It might be recommended for you to call it in order to ensure that the change is still in effect. Only the government of the nation you wish to visit can truly tell you its requirements.